# Initializing js libraries with vite bundling in laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, vite

Im trying to develop a laravel project by using Vite. Normally, i just add the javascript files into my layout file with script tags and that is it.

Now, im trying to apply and understand bundling assets and i have some problems.

I use tailwind in my experimental project. And now, i want to include some js libraries like aos, jqueryui.

This is my app.js file

```
import './bootstrap';
import 'flowbite'
import '@lottiefiles/lottie-player'
import 'aos'
import './custom'
```

and this is my app.blade.php file;

```
<head>
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>
```

I have a file which is named custom.js under resources/js/

In my custom.js, im initializing an example js library like;

AOS.init();

Then in the console, it gives;

**Uncaught ReferenceError: AOS is not defined**

error. Probably, its being initialized before javascript calls the aos module in the
app.js file. I get similar error if i try to import and initialize another js libraries. This was a just example.

i think i have conceptional and logical misunderstanding about the bundling.

May someone assist me to solve this problem and make clear "bundling"?

Answer (score 1):

I am also using Laravel 9 and Vite as the default asset bundler and here is what made it work on my project.

on my `bootstrap.js`, I have this code:

```
import AOS from "aos";
AOS.init();
```

I made the initialization inside the `bootstrap.js` file and everything went fine/working from there.